I am trying to extract data from the website with Python, but although the text at the end of my code works, the data is not entered into Excel
I am trying to extract data from the website with Python, but although the text at the end of my code works, the data is not entered into Excel.
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from openpyxl import Workbook
import requests

url = "http://127.0.0.1:5500/login%20(1).html"
response = requests.get(url)

if response.status_code == 200:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

form_data = {'name': '', 'surname': '', 'id_number': '', 'email': ''}
inputs = soup.find_all('input')
for input_tag in inputs:
    name = input_tag.get('name')
    if name in form_data:
        value = input_tag.get('value', '')
        form_data[name] = value
        
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
ws.append(['Name', 'Surname', 'ID Number', 'Email'])

ws.append([form_data['name'], form_data['surname'], form_data['id_number'], form_data['email']])

wb.save('form_verileri.xlsx')


Have you confirmed that form_data is not empty? Have you run this with Python debugger yet and stepped through to confirm that your loop over inputs is actually running and that the if block runs too?  Another common cause of this problem: looking at the wrong file... :) Are you sure you are really checking the file that it wrote (or are you checking an old file from when you first started debugging your script?) - this is a common mistake.
